# Error paginacion con PHP

Tags: php, mysqli, paginación

recien empiezo a programar en PHP y me encontre con una situacion que no entiendo el porque no funciona.
Estoy intentando realizar una paginacion, para ello hago una consulta en mi base de datos MySQL para obener la cantidad de registros que tengo en una tabla.

```
<?php
 
   require_once('includes/functions/db_conection.php');
   $sql = " SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM articles ";
   $result = $conn->query($sql);
   $fila = $result->fetch_assoc();
   echo 'Número de total de registros: ' . $fila['total'];

?>
```

Pero por alguna razon no funciona, a demas tampoco me termina de mostrar el resto de la pagina que seria:

```
<nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
          <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Anterior</a></li>
            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Siguiente</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>

      </div>
      <!--container-->
    </section>

<?php require_once './includes/templates/footer.php'; ?>
```

el html de la paginacion de bootstrap y mi footer. Si alguno me puede dar una mano lo agradezco! Saludos!

Comment: ¿Qué ocurre con ese código? ¿Muestra algún error? ¿Cuál? ¿No muestra nada (página en blanco)?

Comment: @A.Cedano hola, no muestra ningun error solamente la pagina deja de cargar cuando llega a la parte del php y cuando hago el echo tampoco me muestra el resultado de la consulta, que tendria que ser la cantidad de registros que tengo en la tabla.

Comment: Prueba tus objetos con `var_dump` para ver qué ocurre. Cuando algo no funciona debes usarlo. Por ejemplo: `var_dump($result);` y `var_dump($fila);`

Comment: @A.Cedano cuando hago `var_dump($result);` me devuelve NULL, lo cual tambien me parece raro. Pero tengo otra funcion igual a esta, lo unico que cambia es la consulta ya que su funcion es traerme todos los registros de la tabla y si le hago `var_dump();` tambien me devuelve null. No se si me explico.

Comment: ¿Seguro que la tabla se llama `articles`?  ¿Seguro que la conexión se llama `$conn`? ¿Seguro que el `require_once` está bien? Si puedes revisa el log de errores, ahí te dirá qué error está ocurriendo exactamente.

Comment: Puedes poner esto al principio **sólo temporalmente** para que te muestre en pantalla los errores que está ocurriendo, si tienes dificultad para encontrar el log de errores: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Revisa el log de errores o activa el reporte de errores provisionalmente para ver a qué se debe el fallo.

Comment: @A.Cedano Me tira este error con esos comandos que me pasaste  `Warning: mysqli::query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\MAMP\htdocs\Universo\articles.php on line 21
NULL
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on null in C:\MAMP\htdocs\Universo\articles.php:26 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\MAMP\htdocs\Universo\articles.php on line 26`

Comment: Vuelvo a preguntar: ¿ **Seguro** que tienes una tabla llamada `articles`?

Comment: @A.Cedano Si, estuve trabajando con esa tabla toda la semana

Comment: Parece que la conexión no es válida, sea porque el `require_once` es incorrecto, o porque no se llama `$conn`, o porque la estás cerrando o por otra cosa. Revisa el código de la respuesta, el cual dirá el error exacto.

Comment: @A.Cedano ejecutando el codigo de la respuesta me devuelve error en la consulta, pero probe la consulta en la base de datos y si funciona

Comment: ¿Qué error exactamente?

Comment: @A.Cedano no dice, en la pagina muestra "Error en la consulta: " y nada mas!

Comment: Debes revisar a qué base de datos se está conectando, puede que sea a una donde esa tabla no existe.

Comment: @A.Cedano mi archivo de conexion es al que le hago el require, db_conection.php y lo uso en todos los lugares que hago una consulta a la base de datos y funciona! te dejo el codigo por las dudas `<?php
    $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root12', 'universo');

    if($conn->connect_error){
        echo $error -> $conn->connect_error;
    }
?>` universo se llama la base de datos donde esta la tabla articles

Comment: Muy raro, pues la consulta es correcta, no hay error en ella. Prueba con otra tabla a ver si funciona. Y raro además que no imprima el mensaje de error propio del manejador.

Comment: @A.Cedano muy raro y me llama la atencion que el mismo codigo en otro archivo anda lo mas perfecto. Seguire investigando! Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Revisa este código controlado, el cual te dirá qué está ocurriendo exactamente:

```
<?php
   require_once('includes/functions/db_conection.php');
   if ($conn) { 
       $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM articles";
       if ($result = $conn->query($sql)) {
           if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                $fila = $result->fetch_assoc();
                $msg="Número de total de registros: $fila[total]";
           } else {
            $msg="La consulta no arrojó filas";   
           }
       } else {
           $msg=sprintf("Error en la consulta: %s",$conn->error);
       }
    } else {
        $msg="No hay conexión";
    }
    echo $msg;
```